# How to make the DatePicker display date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datepicker

I have the following DatePicker that prints the dates in the following manner:

`12-10-2017`, `7-10-2017`, `10-2-2017`, `2-2-2017`. So you see, if the day is 1-9, it is being printed as a single digit. And, if the month is between Jan-Sept, then it is being printed as a single digit as well.

**What I require:** 
1. I need to replace `-` with `/`. 
2. I need the DatePicker to print the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` even if the day or the month in the date is a single digit. For example, 2nd Oct 2017 should print like `10/02/2017` and 10th June 2017 should print like `06/10/2017`.

The code for DatePicker is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $("#FromDate").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        orientation: 'bottom'
    });
});
</script>
```

Note: I am working on a ASP.NET WebForm.

Comment: if it's a jquery datepicker, the documentation is pretty straightforward. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453428/net-datepicker-format-gives-mm-dd-yyyy-instead-of-mm-dd-yyyy, which looks similar to your question. It should be enough to set the dateFormat of the js object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(function() {

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();

  });
```

---

Possible format options

"mm/dd/yy" > Default

"yy-mm-dd" > ISO 8601

"d M, y" > Short

"d MM, y" > Medium

"DD, d MM, yy" > Full

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly see the code snippet that I have added to my question. That should give you a better idea of  what I am doing.